# I have a code in java that check date and time , similarly to oystercard

Tags: java, date, time

1. I have create this code to check the date and the time similar as Oyster card. If it is less than one hour, no deduction of the price. If is over one hour, deduct 1.5, but cannot exceed 4.5 because is a dailyCharge.
2. Could I have any suggestions of how I could implement my code to check the date and the time for the last journey?

```
    public boolean touch(int date,int time){
        pvTime = 12;
        double price = 1.5;
        if(balance < 1.5)
            return false;
        if( time == pvTime || pvTime < 60 ) {
            return true;
        }else if(pvTime > 60 ){
            balance-=price;
            dailyCharge = price;
            if(dailyCharge > 4.5) {
                balance= dailyCharge;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Not being familiar with Oyster Card I have no idea what you mean. Sorry.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and make a [mcve]? What is `balance`? Why do you check `pvTime < 60` and `pvTime > 60` when it's always 12 anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use appropriate classes for such data.

Java provides the *java.time* classes for date-time work.

Use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) to record a moment in time as seen from [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (an [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero hours-minutes-seconds).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment.
```

Calculate elapsed time with [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( instant , Instant.now() ) ;
```

Test if an hour elapsed.

```
long hours = duration.toHours() ;
if( hours > 0 ) 
{ 
    // At least one hour elapsed.
} 
else 
{
    // Under an hour.
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, there is any other way without using .toHours or .Date method . I cannot use this methods

Comment: What stops you from using these methods? They are built into Java since Java 8 and also backported to Java 6 and 7.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks for trying to help with the edit, but the math  was wrong. Testing for at least an hour means "> 0", not "> 1">